# How to determine if and which index is being used in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle-sqldeveloper

Could anyone provide instructions on how will I check or verify if the index I created is being used in the query?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a similar question on SO for MySQL db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After "explain plan for" you'll want something like this:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Read this:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/oracle/getting-an-execution-plan
- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/oracle/operations

Comment: Is there a similar question on SO for MySQL db?

Comment: @SandeepanNath If you visit the links above, you'll find a box labeled "This Page for" and then there is also MySQL listed. Just click there, then you'll be at the same content, just for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following setting and then execute the query for the session.

```
   Set Autotrace on;
```

I see that you are using sqldeveloper. When you execute the after setting the autotrace on, the script output window will show the explain plan and the statistics while the query result window will show your output. The explain plan would let you know if the index was used or not for the query executed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in oracle you can use

```
EXPLAIN PLAN for sql
```

It should outline for you which index is being used, if any.

Comment: I executed the above code it just says "Explained"..Where will I checked the result?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in SQLDeveloper, highlight the query and click the "Autotrace" button. Usually, the F6 button corresponds to this action.

[image: SQLDeveloper Autotrace Button]